# Springxd convert from rabbitmq json message as output to a pojo in a custom spark processor module

Tags: apache-spark, spring-integration, spark-streaming, spring-xd

I'm trying to create a stream as the following one:

> rabbitmq | spark-custom-processor | file-sink

RabbitMq read from a queue that has messages, with a header of type application/json, that represent my POJO class `House`. Then these readded messages should be transported to my `spark-custom-processor` and after the processor has done his job, store the result in a file.

The problem is that the type of the data that arrives to the `spark-custom-processor` is `Byte` not the application/json message converted to my POJO class `House`.

If read the documentation where [Type convertion](http://docs.spring.io/spring-xd/docs/current/reference/html/#type-conversion) is explained and it seams that the transformation to my POJO `House` type  should be done automaticaly, but it do not.

Also I've tryed to use:

> rabbitmq | --inputputType=application/x-java-object;type=domain.MetricBean spark-custom-processor | file-sink
>   to especify the convertion but the `springXdShell` comlains about a sintax error at `;`

IS there a way to do it, or must I do the mapping with `ObjectMapper` in my `spark-custom-processor` by myself?

Comment: Try to make it like this `--inputputType="application/x-java-object;type=domain.MetricBean"`

Comment: Yes, but use `'...'` I edited and undeleted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to quote the string with the `;`.

I just tested this and it worked fine...

```
xd:>stream create foo --definition "rabbit --outputType='application/x-java-object;type=foo.Foo' 
    | log" --deploy
```

.

```
public class Foo {

    private String foo;

    public String getFoo() {
        return foo;
    }

    public void setFoo(String foo) {
        this.foo = foo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Foo [foo=" + foo + "]";
    }

}
```

published `{"foo":"bar"}`

```
2015-07-30T10:37:36-0400 1.2.0.RC1 INFO SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 sink.foo - Foo [foo=bar]
```

Comment: Great!!!! It seams so stupid and easy but I haven't try it, neither guess it. @gary-russell Is there a way I can contribute to improve the documentation regarding these topics

Comment: Yes, of course; the project is hosted on GitHub; the best place to start is with the [contributing guidelines](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md). The documentation source files are [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-xd/tree/master/src/docs/asciidoc); it's written in asciidoctor format. We look forward to your first Pull Request!!